# Java - byte array arithmetics on bit-level?

Tags: java, math, arrays, bit

I'm using byte arrays (of size 2 or 4) to emulate the effect of `short` and `int` data types.
Main idea is to have a data type that support both `char` and `int` types, however it is really hard for me to emulate arithmetic operations in this way, since I must do them in bit level.
For those who do not follow:

The `int` representation of 123 is not equal to the byte[] of {0,1,2,3} since their bit representations differ (123 representation is `00000000000000000000000001111011` and the representation of {0,1,2,3}  is `00000000000000010000001000000011` on my system.

So "`int` of 123" would actually be equivalent to "`byte[]` of {0,0,0,123}". The problems occur when values stretch over several bytes and I try to subtract or decrement from those byte arrays, since then you have to interact with several different bytes and my math isn't that sharp.

Any pseudo-code or java library suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Out of interest, what is the problem that you are trying to solve by having all this complexity?

Comment: @NPE In short, I'm trying to emulate registers of a CPU and rewrite assembly level functions in java(and yes, I know that the last part sounds ridiculous).

Comment: @Matas ha, I did wonder if that was what you were trying to do, hence my extended example of just what it can take to emulate those registers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you *really* want to know what bits are being carried from one byte to the next, I'd suggest *don't* do it this way!  If it's just plain math, then convert your arrays to *real* `short` and `int` types, do the math, then convert them back again.

If you *must* do it this way, consider the following:

Imaging you're adding two `short` variables that are in `byte` arrays.

The first problem you have is that all Java integer types are *signed*.

The second is that the "carry" from the least-significant-byte into the most-significant-byte is best done using a type that's *longer* than a `byte` because otherwise you can't detect the overflow.

i.e. if you add two 8-bit values, the carry will be in bit 8.  But a `byte` only has bits `0..7`, so to calculate bit 8 you have to promote your bytes to the next appropriate larger type, do the add operation, then figure out if it resulted in a carry, and then handle that when you add up the MSB.  It's just not worth it.

BTW, I did actually have to do this sort of bit manipulation many years ago when I wrote an MC6809 CPU emulator.  It was necessary to perform multiple operations on the same operands just to be able to figure out the effect on the CPU's various status bits, when those same bits are generated "for free" by a hardware ALU.

For example, my (C++) code to add two 8-bit registers looked like this:

```
void mc6809::help_adc(Byte& x)
{
    Byte    m = fetch_operand();

    {
        Byte    t = (x & 0x0f) + (m & 0x0f) + cc.bit.c;
        cc.bit.h = btst(t, 4);          // Half carry
    }

    {
        Byte    t = (x & 0x7f) + (m & 0x7f) + cc.bit.c;
        cc.bit.v = btst(t, 7);          // Bit 7 carry in
    }

    {
        Word    t = x + m + cc.bit.c;
        cc.bit.c = btst(t, 8);          // Bit 7 carry out
        x = t & 0xff;
    }

    cc.bit.v ^= cc.bit.c;
    cc.bit.n = btst(x, 7);
    cc.bit.z = !x;
}
```

which requires that *three* different additions get done on different variations of the operands just to extract the `h`, `v` and `c` flags.

Comment: All right, I'll try the conversion, and I even forgot the signed byte nuance(completely forgot that), thanks for your answer!